# Understanding the definition of a polynomial over an arbitrary commutative unitary finite Ring R to understand REDEI RATIONAL FUNCTIONS

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, definition

I'm reading a paper that introduce a fast evaluation algorithm for Redei functions.

In the Introduction:

> Let $R$ an arbitrary commutative unitary finite Ring and let $t(x) = x^2 - ax - b$ denote a polynomial over R with the two different roots $\alpha$, $\overline{\alpha}$.

I understand the definition of an arbitrary commutative unitary finite Ring.

I know that $\mathbb{{Z} _{n}^{*}}$ is commutative unitary finite Ring but I don't know how to relate the polynomial $t(x)$.

[Link](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01195335.pdf), if the paper is needed

What is the relation between this polynomial $t(x)$ and $\mathbb{{Z} _{n}^{*}}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: All they are saying is that the coefficients $1,-a,-b$ are elements of the ring.

Comment: The coefficients of your polynomial are in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{*}$. That's all it is saying.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a polynomial over a commutative ring $R$ means that all its coefficients are in $R.\,$ Said equivalently,  $\,f\in R[x] = $ ring of polynomials with coefs $\in R\ \ \ $